# How to extract subvector from a vector?

Tags: c++, sorting, recursion, vector

I'm writing recursive solution for finding minimum element in rotated sorted array. The input for the function is const vector , and i have to get a subarray for recursion.

```
findMin(const vector<int> &A) {
    int l=0,r=A.size()-1;
    if(r<l)return A[0];
    if(r==l)return A[l];

    int m=(l+r)/2;
    if((m<r)&&(A[m+1]<A[m]))
        return A[m+1];
    if((m<r)&&(A[m]<A[m-1]))
        return A[m];
    if(A[m]<A[r]){
        const vector<int> &B(&A[0],&A[m-1]);
        return findMin(B);
    }
    const vector<int> &C(&A[m+1],&A[r]);
    return findMin(C);
}
```

The error is about the sub-vector B and C

Comment: Get an actual sub-array will be very inefficient. Much better to pass the start index and end index of the sub-array as parameters.

Comment: yes,i could do that. but its basically a problem from coding practice site. and all i have to do is finish the given function. I can't change the function parameters. Done everything,stuck at this point.

Comment: If you have constraints that make no sense "in the real world", please mention them in your question.  Include a link to the coding practice site while you are at it, as you can easily misunderstand the rules.

Answer (score 3):

```
const vector<int> &C(&A[m+1],&A[r]);
```

The error you get here is that you are trying to bind a reference, but you are using the syntax for initializing a vector.

The correct way to obtain a sub-vector is

```
const vector<int> C(&A[m+1],&A[r]);
```

note the missing `&`. This, however, will make a copy of the given range, which is undesirable.

As advised in the comment above, change you function parameters to be the vector and a couple of indices, or (perhaps better) to be a couple of iterators.

Answer (score 2):

Vectors store and own data, they are not views into it.  A vector does not have a "subvector", as there are no other objects that own the vector's data.

You can copy data from your vector to another vector, but calling that a "subvector" is misleading.

The easiest solution is to rewrite your function to work with iterator start and finish instead of a container.  You can take your existing interface, and have it call the two-iterator version, to maintain the API.

The harder solution is to write an `array_view<T>` class that stores two `T*` and behaves like a range with the interface you want, including an implicit cast-from-vector.  Replace your `const vector<int>&B` and similarly `C` with a properly written `array_view<int const> B`, as well as your `A`, and (assuming no other errors in your code) you are done.

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29107205/1774667) is an `array_view` I have written.  [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4512.html) is one under the process of being added to `std`.

Answer (score 0):

For this type of recursive functions, using a helper function would be more appropriate as illustrated below:

```
int findMinHelper(std::vector<int> const& rotatedSorted, int left, int right)
{
    if (right == left) return rotatedSorted[left];

    int mid = (right + left) / 2;

    if (mid < right && rotatedSorted[mid + 1] < rotatedSorted[mid])
       return rotatedSorted[mid + 1];

    if (mid > left && rotatedSorted[mid] < rotatedSorted[mid - 1])
       return rotatedSorted[mid];

    if (rotatedSorted[right] > rotatedSorted[mid])
       return findMinHelper(rotatedSorted, left, mid - 1);

    return findMinHelper(rotatedSorted, mid + 1, right);
}

int findMin(std::vector<int> const& rotatedSorted)
{
    // proper handling of the case when rotatedSorted.empty() is true 
    // must be done
    return findMinHelper(rotatedSorted, 0, rotatedSorted.size() - 1);
}
```

Then, you can call:

```
std::vector<int> input{10, 21, 4, 5, 8};
int minValue = findMin(input);
std::cout << minValue << std::endl;
```

which will print 4 as expected.